# how to search for pattern with tolerance in python

Tags: python, extract, sequence, sample, missing-data

Here is my issue. I am trying to collect output from a real time system which decrements its output from 55 to 0 in steps of 1. I am recording this data. I have captured all the data it returns 55,54,53,....3,2,1,. But due to system lag some samples get repeated and some samples are missed
for example, I get

> [55, 53, 52, 52, 51, 50, 49, 48, 47, 46, 45, 44, 43, 42, 41, 39, 38, 38, 36, 36, 34, 33, 33, 32, 31, 30, 29, 28, 27, 26, 25, 24, 23, 22, 21, 20, 20, 18, 17, 15, 14, 13, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 7, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]

So, I have a pattern (55 to 0) but with some samples missed and some samples repeated.
Is there a way I can script this and extract them.

My goal is to verify that 55 to 0 happened in steps of 1 (but that should account for any single misses and repetitions due to sampling ) Here is the code:

```
for x in range(len(b)-1): 
   e += b[x] - b[x+1]
   print x,b[x]-b[x+1], b[x], b[x+1] 
   print 'reached %d count in %d decrements' % (e, len(b)-1)
```

Comment: What would you like to extract? The missed samples? The repeated samples? How many are repeated? Have you tried to write any code to do it yourself?

Comment: I would like to extract the data from 55 to 1 (with misses and repetitions like 55,53,53...) and compare it with the sequence of numbers without repetitions (55,54,53....1) The code should actually ignore if a single sample is missed. In this case it should understand that 54 is missed and 53 is repeated twice and it should move on to find 52. The tolerance should only be 1. For ex: 55,53,52... 1 is okay but 55,52,50,49 is not.

Comment: @rabs I wrote a code which is not robust enough. All it does is: It takes the index in the file when the count is 55 and counts how many steps it took to reach 0. My goal is to verify that 55 to 0 happened in steps of 1. Here is the code                          for x in range(len(b)-1):
 e+=b[x]-b[x+1]
 print x,b[x]-b[x+1], b[x], b[x+1]                          print 'reached %d count in %d decrements' %(e, len(b)-1)

Answer (score 3):

if I understood well, you may want to use numpy diff function :

```
In [1]: import numpy as np 

In [2]: A = [55, 53, 52, 52, 51, 50, 49, 48, 47, 46, 45, 44, 43, 42, 41, 39, 38, 38, 36, 36, 34, 33, 33, 32, 31, 30, 29, 28, 27, 26, 25, 24, 23, 22, 21, 20, 20, 18, 17, 15, 14, 13, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 7, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]


In [3]: np.diff(A)
Out[3]: 
array([-2, -1,  0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -2, -1,  0,
       -2,  0, -2, -1,  0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
       -1,  0, -2, -1, -2, -1, -1,  0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,  0, -2, -1,
       -1, -1, -1])
```

Where -1 is an expected step of 1, -2 is a missing step, and 0 a repeat.
And if you want to know where are the problems :

```
In [4]: np.where(np.diff(A) != -1)[0] # [0] because it's 1D array
Out[4]: array([ 0,  2, 14, 16, 17, 18, 19, 21, 35, 36, 38, 41, 48, 49])
```

Tell me if it's not clear.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, if you want the set of all samples found, the set of those not found, and those that are repeated:

```
b = [55, 53, 52, 52, 51, 50, 49, 48, 47, 46, 45, 44, 43, 42, 41, 39, 38, 38, 36, 36, 34, 33, 33, 32, 31, 30, 29, 28, 27, 26, 25, 24, 23, 22, 21, 20, 20, 18, 17, 15, 14, 13, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 7, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]

unique_b = set(b)
not_in_b = [x for x in xrange(1, 56) if x not in b]
repeats_in_b = [x for x in xrange(1,56) if b.count(x) > 1]

print unique_b
print not_in_b
print repeats_in_b

>>>set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 17, 18, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 36, 38, 39, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 55])
>>>[6, 16, 19, 35, 37, 40, 54]
>>>[7, 13, 20, 33, 36, 38, 52]
```